# How much current used in 20 LEDs circuit?

Tags: led, current, circuit-analysis

If I have 20 LEDs (red) and I want to connect it in parallel and series.
Which circuit need more current? and how much?

*And what happen if I use a source that can provide current both less than and more than the circuit need?
Thank you ^^

Comment: "more minimum current" meaning what exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I mean how much current needed in each circuit.

Comment: look at the datasheet of the LEDs, it tells you with how much current you should drive them.

Comment: I know that 1 LED need 20 mA approximately. But how to calculate 20 LEDs ?.

Comment: It depends on the voltage you have available.

Comment: Whatever you connection, whether it is serial, parallel or combination of both this, Power will be same.

Comment: @Raj LED power will be exactly the same. Total power might be quite a bit different if you can use series or series/parallel combinations. Eg. 20 LEDs 2V with individual resistors from 5V = 2W. If in series/parallel strings with one resistor per series pair, power drops to 1W total (and half the resistors).

Answer (score 4):

20 red leds (so 2.0 Vf at 20 mA) in series is 20 * 2.0 = 40 volts at 20 miliamps.  That's 40 * 0.02 = 0.8 Watts.

20 red leds in parallel is 20 * 0.02 = 0.4 Amps or 400 mA at 2 Volts. That's 2 * 0.4 = 0.8 Watts.

There is no difference in power used, just how you wire it. Current is shared in Series circuits, Voltage is shared in Parallel circuits.

This doesn't take into account resistors or current overhead. You need a current limiting resistor, or a constant current source. Arrange the leds as best suiting your power source or needs.

Comment: @NutthanonPhongchawalit just be sure not to put all the LEDs in parallel without a current limiting resistor for each LED. In series only requires one common current limiting resistor.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you for your recommend. I used to connect 3mm white and red in parallel, white need 2.8 - 3.5 volts red need 1.8 - 2.4 volts. So only red flashed up. I think this happen because I don't connect a resistor to the red. right? and then I try to use resistor to the red and after that it work!

Comment: I forget to tell you that I use 3 volts source.